# ASP.NET Core route receiving values as null

Tags: json, asp.net-core

When testing with postman, I put in the following JSON format:

[image]

It hits the method just fine, but the problem is that the value of `body` is null, I do not know why this is happening. [image]

Also, I have tried changing `Blog` to `dynamic` and I get to see the Json that I had sent to it.

[image]

This is my `Blog` class:

```
public class Blog
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public string PostedByUserName { get; set; }
    }
```

On `ConfigureServices.cs` I do have NewtonsoftJson setup with this line of code:

```
services.AddMvcCore().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

What could be my issue?

Comment: You are sending an array that's the issue (remove the square braces)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sendind a json array `[...]` while the endpoint expects an object. The following payload should work (without square brackets)

```
{
    "title": "test",
    "body": "sometest"
}
```

Comment: just noticed it is not required to be an array, it works now